# WordPress custom image loop

Tags: wordpress, attachment, meta-key

I would like to create a loop with images per post ID. These are custom images which are made by the theme I’ve bought. These images have a meta_key called “estate_property_images”.
This is the code I’ve made, but post with no image are showing images what isn’t possible.

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
     'orderby' => 'post__in',
     'post__in' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'estate_property_images', false ));   

$gallery_array = get_posts( $args );

foreach ($gallery_array as $slide) {
    $attachment = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $slide->ID, 'full' );
            $attachment_url = $attachment[0];
    $xml .= "\t\t<afbeeldingURL>".$attachment_url."</afbeeldingURL>\n";
}
```

Can somebody help me fix this problem?

Comment: What are the outputs of `$gallery_array` and `$attachment`?

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden How can I check the outputs?

Comment: You could use `var_dump()` or `print_r()` for arrays and objects.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden $gallery_array: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qpbh3gcosd8a47y/gallery_array.rtf?dl=0
$attachment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/un9oufu2e89o7qd/attachment.rtf?dl=0

Comment: So these vars are no arrays?

Comment: I don't know much about this. I have searched for a solution but I can't find it. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82593/discussion-between-ron-van-der-heijden-and-caat).